# Отправка данных в MySQL aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я создаю телеграм бота, который получает определённые данные в users, но когда я их пытаюсь таким образом засунуть в бд

```
def paste_user(user, connection):
    create_users = "INSERT INTO `users`(`uni`, `department`, `direction`, `subject`, `type_work`, `date`) VALUES ('"+user['uni']+"','"+user['department']+"','"+user['direction']+"','"+user['subject']+"','"+user['type_work']+"','"+user['date']+"')"
    execute_query(connection, create_users)
```

мне выдает вот такую вот ошибку:
create_users = "INSERT INTO `users`(`uni`, `department`, `direction`, `subject`, `type_work`, `date`) VALUES ('"+user['uni']+"','"+user['department']+"','"+user['direction']+"','"+user['subject']+"','"+user['type_work']+"','"+user['date']+"')"
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Если я не делаю конкатенацию строк и не указываю id то всё работает корректно, подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема.

Вот сама таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  uni TEXT,
  department TEXT,
  direction TEXT,
  subject TEXT,
  type_work TEXT,
  date TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

При помощи этой функции выполняю все манипуляции с бд

```
def execute_query(connection, query):
     cursor = connection.cursor()
     try:
         cursor.execute(query)
         connection.commit()
         print("Query executed successfully")
     except Error as e:
         print(f"The error '{e}' occurred")
```

Comment: А что такое user ? Судя по тексту ошибки это list, а не dict и полей по именам вы там не найдете. P.S. где вы научились так работать с БД, конкатенируя строки. Во всех примерах работы с MySQL указано, что значения в текст надо подставлять как %s, а значения для подстановки передавать в execute. Это единственный безопасный способ. Посмотрите примеры в документации https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/#documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так. Это хотя бы выведет ошибку понятнее, и вы сможете её отследить.

```
def paste_user(user, connection):
    create_users = f"INSERT INTO `users`(`uni`, `department`, `direction`, `subject`, `type_work`, `date`) VALUES ({user['uni']},{user['department']},{user['direction']},{user['subject']},{user['type_work']},{user['date']})"
    execute_query(connection, create_users)
```